# Getting an error then tryiing to display some text in alert window together with array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, alert

I am trying to make alert script to display some array values together with some text.

The code with: `alert(numbers[i] + " is" + student[i] );` works fine but if I add some text before `numbers[i]` it is not working I tried both single and double quotes no luck.

```
<button onclick="students()">Try now</button>
<script>
  function students() {
    var student = ["Maria", "Jane", "Sue", "Mary", "Amber"];
    var numbers = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"];
    for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
      alert(numbers[i] + " is" + student[i]);
    }
  }
</script>
```

This doesn't work:

```
alert("In the student list" numbers[i] + " is" + student[i] );
```

Comment: missing one `+`: `alert("In the student list" numbers[i] ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create valid string first and you will see missing '+':

```js
var message = "In the student list " + numbers[i] + " is" + student[i];
alert(message)
```